# Can XML attributes be exploited?

Tags: xml

on my website i deliver an xml, whereas GET parameters will be added as (entityencoded) attributes somewhere in the xml.

stripped down example:

```
http://host/file.xml?x=y
```

leads to

```
<root>
  <element x="y" />
</root>
```

note that the string is being html entity encoded so you cant really escape out of the quotes. a string like this

```
"/>
```

leads to

```
&quot;/&gt;
```

but could this be exploited another way?

Comment: I guess it would be easier for us if you post the code that generates the XML output.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't give us information about how the XML is used/parsed afterwards. Still I've got two points on this:

- By using something like `http://host/file.xml?a=b%20x=y` someone will be able to add an additional attribute depending on how you deal with the output, this might be a problem. Also some parsers take the first occurrence of an attribute, some the last and some even concatenate values with the same key. So what about `http://host/file.xml?x=z%20x=y` which may result in something like `<element x=z x="y" />` (of course this also depends on how strict your parser is and what values are accepted for `x`.
- Depending on the parser, there might be ways to encode characters like `"/>` when sending them to your application without them being HTML entity encoded.

If you provide more information, we might be able to give you a more specific answer. Anyway, I would highly recommend not to insert unchecked user input into any XML. If really needed, you should at least use some kind of filtering (the best would be a whitelisting of accepted values or at least a regex for what you want to accept). In addition, the XML parser should also be provided a schema to validate the XML.